# MediaRecorder OnInfoListener giving an 895

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I'm using MediaRecorder to allow users to record audio in my app, and for the vast majority of them (and on all my test devices) it is working fine. The relevant code looks like this:

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

        String audioFilePath = mUri.getPath();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(256 * 1024);
        mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

        mRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); 

        try{
            mRecorder.prepare();
        }catch (IOException ex){
            Log.e(TAG, "Prepare() failed", ex);

            mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ExceptionBuilder()
            .setDescription("Preparing MediaRecorder in : " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ": " + ex.toString())
            .setFatal(false)
            .build()
            );
        }
        mRecorder.start();
```

I have had a report from a user that they are not able to record audio, the toast message that they see is one that I trigger from within the MediaRecorder.onInfoListener.

So I added some Google Analytics and record an event from within that listener to see if I can track down the error:

```
private MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener infoListener = new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            mr.stop();
            mr.reset();
            mr.release();
            mr = null;
            onRecordingStopped();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.audio_recording_stopped, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory("Error")
            .setAction("AudioStopped")
            .setLabel("What: " + what + ", extra: " + extra)
            .build());
        }
    };
```

As you can see I am passing through the 'what' and 'extra' parameters to my Analytics so I can see what kind of errors are occuring.

In my analytics this morning (with just a day of data to go on so far) I am seeing a few with a 'what' of 800 which I can see in the documentation is max duration reached, but the others have  a 'what' of 895 which I can find no reference to in the Media.Recorder documentation.

Any suggestions for what 895 means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. Turns out on my device info code 895 meant recording in progress.
That means you don't need to stop the recording.